# Pass different values according to button pressed in same RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My problems and needs are kept in comments. Any help and suggestions are appreciated. Need Output Like below:

[This is what I perfectly Want. With Same recyclerView but different Value with Different Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgybR.jpg)

```
public class Recycler extends Fragment {
private List<Name> names;
RecyclerView rv;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview,container,false);

    rv= (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv);

    LinearLayoutManager llm=new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
    initializeData();

    initializeAdapter();
    return view;
}

private void initializeAdapter() {
rvadapter adapter=new rvadapter(names);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void initializeData() {
    names=new ArrayList<>();
    //names.add(new Name("Nikesh"));
    //There are three buttons on First Fragment, If Button 1 is pressed only textview should change and similarly rest for another two buttons
    //Pass Data Here According To Button Pressed In the First Fragment
    //Example
    //If I pressed button 1 then print names.add(new Name("From First"));
    //If I pressed button 1 then print names.add(new Name("From Second"));
    //If I pressed button 1 then print names.add(new Name("From Third"));

    //Better If I can pass here value From Click Listener from MainActivity Button1

}
```

}

```
//This is Main_Activity and its a Activity
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.img_boy:
         //  cardView cardview=new cardView();
            Recycler rc=new Recycler();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,rc);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            //Wish I can Pass value from here
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a value to a fragment using a Bundle.

**Inside your OnClick**

```
Recycler recycler = new Recycler();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("key", "value");
recycler.setArguments(bundle);
// ...
```

**Inside your RecyclerFragment**

```java
private String mValue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(getArguments() != null){
    mValue = getArguments().getString("key");
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the picture? Where do i pass value? and In your code RecyclerFragment contains onCreate method.

Comment: Pass your value where it says "value". onCreate is a lifecycle method called before onCreateView.

Comment: I know your code should work but its not  displaying text i did is




      Recycler rc=new Recycler();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key", "Okie Dockie");
                rc.setArguments(bundle);

and then in Recycler

 names=new ArrayList<>();
        String mValue = null;
        if(getArguments()!=null){

            mvalue=getArguments().getString("key");
            names.add(new Name(mValue));
        }

Comment: Did you finish the whole fragmentTransaction things and commit? If yes, what happens if you put a Log.d("Fragment","inside onCreate, inside if"); below mValue=".."

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `onClickListener` interface to your `RecyclerView.Adapter`. With this you can return the `Name` for which button was clicked, then start a new `Activity` or inflate a new `Fragment` based on that.

Comment: Will you please do a example for me?  I am a newbie and i can't understand these shortcut way. You can point me to some documentation link. :)

Comment: @AppleAppala The link I provided has an example of how to do so. It is difficult to provide a more robust example without more information. For example, where are you getting the information for the new list (after you click on one of the items from the current list)? Have you implemented a [`RecyclerView.Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) yet, or have you not gotten that far?

Comment: ya i have implemented that ;)

Comment: @AppleAppala So then, all you should have to do is add the code from the [link I originally provided](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/96/recyclerview-onclicklisteners/5077/item-click-listeners#t=201608121651540289586) to listen for clicks on each `RecyclerView` item. Then you can display the new data based on which item was clicked.

Comment: Did you saw the picture I posted above? Click on the Link above  "This is perfectly What I want" I am able to use click Listeners, I just need is 3 different buttons use same recyclerView and whole process but  the content(TextView) inside recyclerView is only be changing. This is What  I wanted.